# output file issue in c++

Tags: c++, file

I keep getting an "no matching function" error when i compile this code. Can someone help me out with this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string filename[]="Hello.txt";
  ofstream OutFile;
  OutFile.open(filename);
  if(OutFile.fail()) // check for successfully open ,
   {
    cout << "file named can not be found \n";
    exit(1);
   } 
    OutFile << "Hello, this is my output file";
    OutFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
What about when reading and displaing a file? I'm having issues with the getline and it won't compile. Can anyone point out the issue there?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

  char filename[] = "Hello.txt";

  string line = "Hello, this is my output file";

  ofstream OutFile;

  OutFile.open(filename);

  if(OutFile.fail()) // check for successfully open ,

   {

     cout << "file named can not be found \n";

     exit(1);

   } 

     OutFile << line;

     if (OutFile.is_open())

       OutFile.getline(line);

    OutFile.close();

     system("pause");

}
```

Comment: It's a single argument (single string argument) function - OutFile.open(filename). You are using an array of filenames. Your error stack trace should show you. Use a single string instead.

Comment: And please, next time when you get an error, tell us in which line the error occurs and which compiler you're using.

Answer (score 4):

`open()` takes a single `string`, not an array of strings.

You're creating an array (of one).  Try this instead:

```
string filename = "Hello.txt";
ofstream OutFile;
OutFile.open(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: i just made that correction and its still giving me the same error

Comment: You need to use `filename.c_str()`. `open` wasn't changed to use a `std::string` until C++11

Comment: @jon it shouldnt [it compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5376d442732033b4) if you remove `[]`

Comment: So for strings I have to use filename.c_str? I did it for char and it works fine

Comment: Good point, @AndyG - I tested under C++ 11. Made a backwards-compatible edit.

Comment: @jon `std::string::c_str()` returns a c-string, so it's the same. If you want to give it a `std::string`, then you have to compile with C++11 or later.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `string[]` instead of `string` or `char[]`, so you are defining an array of strings, rather than a single string.

`open` accepts a single `string` rather than multiple strings, where a single `string` is multiple characters/a character array.